# Moving data from listbox in one form to a listbox in another (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I'm a total novice at C# (have been learning Java til now) and this is my first time posting! I've had a look around the forum but can't find what I need.

I'm trying to move details of a string from a list box in one form to a list box in another form - it's supposed to be an email client.

The original data is taken in by a stream reader and split into name and email.

Here's the code section for the form that has the data (frmAddressBook):

```
public void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                                 
             if (tmpLine.StartsWith(lstAddresses.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                //Split the line.
                namesEmailAddresses = tmpLine.Split(',');

                lstTest.Items.Add(namesEmailAddresses[0] + ", " + namesEmailAddresses[1]);

                frmWorldEmail frmWE = new frmWorldEmail();
                frmWE.names = namesEmailAddresses[0];
                frmWE.emails = namesEmailAddresses[1];
                frmWE.Show();    

                }//if       

            }
```

And the code section of the form I'm trying to get the data into (frmWorldEmail):

```
public partial class frmWorldEmail : Form
{
   public frmWorldEmail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string names 
    {
        get { 
            names = this.names; 
            return names; 
        }
        set { }
    }

    public string emails
    {
        get {
            emails = this.emails;
            return emails; 
        }
        set { }
    }

    public void lstNameTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstNameTo.Items.Add(names);
        lstNameTo.Show();            
    }

    public void lstEmailTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstEmailTo.Items.Add(emails);        
        lstEmailTo.Show();            
    }      
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, don't use those empty setters.  Use them to add the items to the listbox.

Comment: To start with class and methods names should start with uppercase.

Comment: And why are you using a list if there is only one name/email coming from the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this. I don't get it what you're adding the items in the selected index changed event

```
 public partial class frmWorldEmail : Form
 {
      public frmWorldEmail(string names, string emails)
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         lstNameTo.Items.Add(names);
         lstEmailTo.Items.Add(emails);
      }     
  }
```